# Some Continuity Question

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Suppose $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous functions on $[a,b]$ with $f$ monotone increasing. Assume there exists a sequence $x_n \in [a, b]$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ , $g(x_n) = f(x_{n+1})$. Show that there exists $x_0 \in [a,b]$ such that $g(x_0) = f(x_0)$.

Just wondering if this question is wrong. My idea is that if I look at $g(x) := x+1$ and $f(x) := x$. Choosing the sequence $x_n = x$. Then I have  $g(x) = f(x+1)$. However, I don't think there is any $x_0$ such that $x_0 + 1 = x_0$. What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: You need to work on a (compact) interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: This seems to be basically the same question as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/761299/tough-continuous-function-limit-question (Maybe you are classmates?)

Comment: @Martin Sleziak Really thank you for helping me to solve my past unanswered questions. Maybe haha

Comment: If you still think that your $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ are a counterexample, try to find a sequence $x_n$, with the required properties. (You start with some $x_1$. Then $x_2$ must be $x_2=x_1+1$. Can you keep this sequence within $[a,b]$?)

Comment: However, it is a counterexample showing that the claim is not true for functions $f,g\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. See [this chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15173896#15173896) for more details.

Comment: @Martin Sleziak can you provide me with two functions that fulfil this property, so that i can better understand the formula. SO far, i still can't get an intuitive feel of what the question is trying to tell me

Comment: Since I did not want to post too many lengthy comment here, I have posted [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15176328#15176328).

Comment: thanks a lot for the examples