# If there exist sequence such that $g(x_n)=f(x_{n+1})$, then we have $g(x_0)=f(x_0)$ for some $x_0$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous functions on $[a,b]$ with $f$ monotone increasing. Assume there exists a sequence $x_n \in [a, b]$ such that for all $n \in N$ , $g(x_n) = f(x_{n+1})$. Show that there exists $x_0 \in [a,b]$ such that $g(x_0) = f(x_0)$.

Can someone provide an example of functions that fulfills this condition?

Comment: I really need help in solving this

Answer (score 2):

If there is an $n$ such that $g(x_n)=f(x_n)$, we are done. So let us assume that $g(x_n)\ne f(x_n)$ for each $n$.

Now if $g(x_n)>f(x_n)$ and $g(x_{n+1})<f(x_{n+1})$, then the continuity of $f$ and $g$ implies that and $x$ such that $f(x)=g(x)$ exists somewhere between $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$.

The case that $g(x_n)<f(x_n)$ and $g(x_{n+1})>f(x_{n+1})$ is basically the same.

So the only two remaining cases are:
A. $(\forall n) g(x_n)>f(x_n)$
B. $(\forall n) g(x_n)<f(x_n)$

Let us discuss the case A. (The case B is similar.)

For each $n$ we have $f(x_n)<g(x_n)=f(x_{n+1})$. Since $f$ is increasing, this implies $x_n<x_{n+1}$, i.e. the sequence $(x_n)$ is monotone.

Every monotone bounded sequence must have a limit, so there exists an $x$ such that
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n=x.$$
Now we get, using the continuity of $f$ and $g$, that
$$f(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(x_{n+1})=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} g(x_n)=g(x).$$

Comment: why is f(x) = n, g(x) = n+1 not a counterexample?

Comment: @user136266 Do you mean constant functions? They do not fulfill the assumptions. (You cannot find $x_n$ with the required properties.)

Comment: I will repost also here link to the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15173896#15173896) where some examples and clarifications related to this were given. (I have already mentioned this in comments to the [duplicate question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/753243/some-continuity-question).)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Prove that there is a monotonic subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}$ and let be $n_0$ the limit of that subsequence.

Comment: I know how to prove that but how does it help? Using Bolzano theorem, this fact is obvious

Answer (score 0):

In fact, this problem can be strengthened as, let $f(x), g(x) \in C[0,1]$, if there is an infinite point set $x_n \in[0,1]$, such that $f\left(x_n\right)=g\left(x_{n+1}\right)$ $(n=1,2, \ldots)$, then there must be a point $\xi \in[0,1]$, Make $f(\xi)=g(\xi)$.

Proof: Use proof by contradiction, if the proposition is not true, that is, there is no point $\xi \in[0,1]$, such that $f(\xi)=g(\xi)$, note $\varphi(x)=g( x)-f(x)$, then $\varphi (x)>0$ or $\varphi (x)<0$ is always true on $[0,1]$. Let $\varphi(x) <0$ is always true on $[0,1]$, so we have,
$$
\varphi(x_{n+1})=g(x_{n+1})-f(x_{n+1})=f(x_n)-f(x_{n+1})<0,n\ in\mathbb N^*
$$
That is, $\{f(x_n)\}$ is monotonically increasing, and since $f(x)$ is a continuous function on the closed interval $[0,1]$, we can know that $\{f(x_n)\}$ is bounded, Therefore, from the monotonic bounded theorem and $f([0,1])$ being a closed set, it can be seen that $x_0\in [0,1]$ exists, such that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}g(x_{n+1})=\lim_{n\to\infty}g(x_{n})= f(x_0)
$$
Thereby there is
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)-g(x_n)=0
$$
On the other hand, note that $\{x_n\}\subset [0,1]$ is a bounded infinite point sequence, so there is a subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ that converges from $[0,1 ]$ is a closed set and we know that there exists $\xi\in[0,1]$ such that
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}f(x_{n_k})-g(x_{n_k})=f(\lim_{k\to\infty}x_{n_k})-g(\lim_{n\to \infty}x_{n_k})=f(\xi)-g(\xi)=\varphi(\xi)=0
$$
contradiction, so the original proposition is established. Q.E.D.